# Execute a while loop while user's password is invalid

Tags: java, string, swing, while-loop, passwords

I'm trying to write a program that prompts a user for a password then, depending on whether the password is "valid", prints the password on the command prompt or tells the user to enter a password again. The user has 3 tries until the program is terminated.

My while loop, that is supposed to run until the passString variable is valid (determined by the isPasswordValid method) or the user has had three tries.

The problem is my while loop never executes even though I initialized passString to an "invalid" password. isPasswordValid should return false the first time the program runs and therefore execute the loop.

currently my program prints out "your password is: ", it doesn't have a password to print because the loop never executes therefore never prompts the user for a password.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Password {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter a password:");
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);

         //place the label and the password field on the JPanel container
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(pass);

        String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};

        int tries = 0;

        String passString = "";

        while (!isValidPassword(passString) && tries < 3) {
             //I've tried isValidPassword(passString) == false
             //and the loop still did not execute

            int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The title",
            JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[1]);

            char[] password = pass.getPassword();

            StringBuilder glue = new StringBuilder();

            for (int x = 0; x < password.length; x++) {

            glue.append(password[x]);
            passString = glue.toString();

            }
            tries++;
        }


        System.out.print("Your password is: " + passString);

    }

    public static boolean isValidPassword(String word) {
        int intCounter = 0;
        int letCounter = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {

            if (Character.isDigit(x) ){

                intCounter++;
            }


            if(Character.isLetter(x)) {

                letCounter++;           

            }

            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(x)) {

                return false;

            }       

        }


        if (intCounter >= 2 && word.length() <= 8) {

            return true;

        }

    return true;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your isValidPassword function does not account for an empty string to be passed into it, so it is completely skipping your main "for" block and then returning true by default at the very end of the function. You need to return false in the very beginning if the string is empty.

Comment: I have added:

if (word.isEmpty()) {
            
            return false;
        
        }

to my method. The program now successfully prompts the user for a password. The problem now is, even if I enter a password that fits the criteria needed for a "valid" password, the program keeps asking the user until they run out of attempts and the loop exits.

Comment: I am not sure what constitutes a valid password. From reading your function, I would say it is:

Comment: Must be length of 1 to 8 characters, must include at least 2 digits, cannot include special characters. Is this correct?  @Jason_Silva

Comment: Yes that's exactly what my goal is.

Comment: @Jason_Silva I am sorry I did not notice this earlier (I am on a plane haha). You are comparing "x" to conditions in your for block -- and "x" is an integer. You should be querying the character like so in each iteration:  char c = word.charAt(x); and then checking its validity.